# Jquery mobile: scale to fit tot mobile screen sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

I am new to jquery mobile, but I have this one question I can't seem to figure out:

I have designed a mobile page which fits perfectly from top to down at a Screensize 800x480. When I test this page on a screen with size 1280x720, the backgroundcolor has to fill up the space for like one third (bottom of the page till end of screen).

How can I extract this so it will fit the whole screen like it does at a 800x480 screen?

Comment: Please provide example code or a link to [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Need your code for more explaination.
But still you can try to use

1) Header

2) Content

3) Footer in page format of Jquery mobile.

4) And then include its css & js.

Customize them according to your requirements.Hope this helps.